# I am trying to make port scanner

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

enter code here

I am trying to make port scanner. I set port range 1 to 100 and try to scan my own router ip, in my router ip port 80 an and 53 is open

```
import socket
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=raw_input("Enter the target host")
for port in range(1,100):
 if s.connect_ex((host,port))==0:
  print("port %d is open" %(port))
  s.close()
 else:
    print("port(>) %d is close" %(port))
```

but, in result port_scanner only show port 53 open and after 53 returns an error

```
> > > > port(>) 44 is close
> > > > port(>) 45 is close
> > > > port(>) 46 is close
> > > > port(>) 47 is close
> > > > port(>) 48 is close
> > > > port(>) 49 is close
> > > > port(>) 50 is close
> > > > port(>) 51 is close
> > > > port(>) 52 is close
> > > > port 53 is open

Trace back (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IYI\Desktop\new.py", line 5, in <module>
    if s. connect _ex((host, port))==0:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr (self.sock,name)(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Err no 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same socket for every attempt. You're also closing that single socket once you find an open port. That means once you find an open port, the next attempt will try to call `connect_ex` on a closed socket.

Create a new socket one each attempt; or at least once you find an open port. I'm not sure if sockets are in a proper state if they fail during a call to `connect` though, so for safety you may want to create a new one each time. When I've made port scanners previously, it worked out fine.